# Resetting Mujoco Environments to a given state

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, mujoco

Aim :
For a mujoco environment (I'm using Metaworld) for example - "Sweep-into", I want to do this :

Reset Environment :
Take some actions ...
sim_state = Save the current state
Take some actions ...

```py
    env.seed(0)
    env.reset()
    env.step() ... several times
    sim_state = env.sim.get_state()
    img = env.render('rgb_array')
    env.step() ... several actions
```

Then :
Reset Environment

```
    env.seed(0)
    env.reset()
    env.sim.set_state(sim_state)
    img_loaded = env.render('rgb_array') 
    sim_state_loaded = env.sim.get_state()
```

I find that sim_state_loaded is same as `env.sim.get_state()` but the image (img != img_loaded) is not the same.
I only care about getting the image after setting the state.

I have already tried playing around by setting the seed before hand.

There are some domains where using `env.set_state(qpos, qvel)` [not env.sim.set_state] will return the same image observation but using that same env object doesn't render valid images / states etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Metaworld, but in principle some computation (e.g., kinematics) is needed between writing a new value into the state vector and calling the render function.  If neither `set_state` nor `render` call these functions, this would explain the failure mode you've hit.

Try to call `env.step` before calling `render`, and if that fixes things you know what's missing.  If calling `step` is unacceptable (e.g., because you don't want to advance the simulation), look for a way to call `mj_forward` with the underlying `mjModel` and `mjData` structs.